# Android - Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an issue that is causing my app to crash when I try to open the activity. This is the line that causing the issue:     Person person = postSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);. I have tried other solutions such as removing the postSnapshot but it hasn't worked. This code works fine on two other activities so I'm completely lost as why it's not working now.

**The Error:**

```
E/UncaughtException: com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
                                                        at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:185)
                                                        at uk.co.jaunt_app.jaunt.PlanTripActivity$7.onDataChange(PlanTripActivity.java:264)
                                                        at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45)
                                                        at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
                                                        at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                                                     Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class uk.co.jaunt_app.jaunt.Person] from String value; no single-String constructor/factory method
```

**The Code:**

```
planRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (final DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //Getting the data from snapshot

                    Person person = postSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);
                    final String planName = person.getPlanName();
                    final String planLat = person.getPlanLat();
                    final String planLong = person.getPlanLong();

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    feedPop.add(
                            new planPinsFeed(planName, planLat, planLong));

                    final ArrayAdapter<planPinsFeed> adapter = new feed2ArrayAdapter(PlanTripActivity.this, 0, feedPop);

                    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customListView2);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {

                            String newPlanLocName = feedPop.get(position).getFeedPlanLocName().toString();
                            String newPlanLocLat = feedPop.get(position).getFeedPlanLat().toString();
                            String newPlanLocLong = feedPop.get(position).getFeedPlanLong().toString();

                            double plannewlat = Double.valueOf(newPlanLocLat);
                            double plannewlong = Double.valueOf(newPlanLocLong);

                            LatLng New = new LatLng(plannewlat, plannewlong);
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(New).title(newPlanLocName).draggable(true)
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mappin)));
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(New, 14 ));
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
```

Comment: Show us your database structure.

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: Your code is expecting each child of `planRef` to be a `Person`.  The error message says one of the children is a simple `String`.  Check that `planRef` is pointing to the right location in your database.

Comment: @BobSnyder thank you for your help. There was a string in the database so I have now removed it and the problem has been solved!

Comment: I also notice that you are using the legacy Firebase SDK.  If your project is still in development, you would be wise to upgrade to the current (11.x.x) SDK.